# Problem with the print of a python tree data structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this program in `m_tree.print_values(root)` appears the **data** and 3 times **None** to any Node present in this tree. I don't understand why appears these None because the function should print only the value.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def print_values(self, root):
        if root != None:
            print(root.data)
            print(self.print_values(root.left))
            print(self.print_values(root.right))
        #Define other tree operations that you want to perform here

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left=left
        self.right=right

#Create a root node
root = Node(0)

#Create a tree with the root node
m_tree = Tree(root)


#Add a left and right node to the root
left_node = Node(3)
right_node = Node(4)
root.left = left_node
root.right = right_node

m_tree.print_values(root)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print_values has no `return` statement, so it returns None by default. So if you call `print_values` and print the result, it will print None.

Change your recursive calls so that they call `print_values` without printing the result.

```
def print_values(self, root):
    if root != None:
        print(root.data)
        self.print_values(root.left)
        self.print_values(root.right)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling

```
print(self.print_values(root.left))
```

The `self.print_values` function *prints* the values, and then *returns* `None`. So first you get the value printed by `print_values`, and then you `print(None)` because that's what `self.print_values` returned.